# Is it allowed in THREE.js to create a mesh with an array of materials containing less elements than the number of sides in the geometry?

Tags: three.js, mesh, raycasting

In my case I ran into an issue when raycasting a cylinder which was defined using CylinderGeometry and an array of materials with length 2 (instead of 3).
I could not find anything in the documentation about requirements for the array of materials, so any array should be allowed?
But when raycasting it could not handle the case that the array element in the materials array is undefined and an exception was thrown.
I propose that either the documentation is changed to be a little more specific about the number of required elements in the array of materials or that the raycasting is changed so that it can handle undefined material elements. In my opinion the natural behavior would be to handle an undefined material as a backside so that no intersection is detected. But, what do you think?